# How to deploy after a build with TeamCity?

Tags: c#, asp.net, deployment, teamcity

I'm setting up TeamCity as my build server.

I have my project set up, it is updating correctly from subversion, and building ok.

So what's next?

Ideally, I'd like to have it auto deploy to a test server, with a manual deploy to a live/staging server.

What's the best way to go about this?

Since I am using C#/ASP.Net, should I add a Web Deployment project to my solution?

Comment: Have you seen Inedo's BuildMaster? A common workflow I see is to have build artifacts pulled out of TeamCity, and deployed/configured with BuildMaster to various servers. Quick reference article: http://inedo.com/support/kb/1031/integrating-jetbrains-teamcity-with-buildmaster (disclaimer: I work for Inedo)

Comment: I made a similar recommendation before, but I do not work for Inedo. It's worth looking at.

Answer (score 61, accepted):

This article explains how to call Microsoft's WebDeploy tool from TeamCity to deploy a web application to a remote web server. I've been using it to deploy to a test web server and run selenium tests on check-in.

[http://www.mikevalenty.com/automatic-deployment-from-teamcity-using-webdeploy/](http://www.agileatwork.com/automatic-deployment-from-teamcity-using-webdeploy/)

1. Install WebDeploy
2. Enable Web config transforms
3. Configure TeamCity BuildRunner
4. Configure TeamCity Build Dependencies

The MSBuild arguments that worked for my application were:

```
/p:Configuration=QA  
/p:OutputPath=bin  
/p:DeployOnBuild=True  
/p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish  
/p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://myserver:8172/msdeploy.axd  
/p:username=myusername  
/p:password=mypassword  
/p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True  
/p:DeployIisAppPath=ci  
/p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC
```

Comment: how do i set email notification once the deployment complete?

Comment: @Michael Valenty: I tried the given solution as`MSBuild.exe C:\BuildAgent\work\4c7b8ac8bc7d723e\WebService.sln /p:Configuration=Release /p:OutputPath=bin /p:DeployOnBuild=True /p:DeployTarget=MSDeployPublish /p:MsDeployServiceUrl=https://204.158.674.5/msdeploy.axd /p:username=Admin /p:password=Password#321 /p:AllowUntrustedCertificate=True /p:DeployIisAppPath=Default WebSite/New /p:MSDeployPublishMethod=WMSVC`. It gives me an error `
MSBUILD : error MSB1008: Only one project can be specified.
Switch: WebSite/New`

Answer (score 14):

I've written a pretty long blog post on this very topic that may interest you:

http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2010/05/09/automated-site-deployments-with-teamcity-deployment-projects-amp-svn

basically:

- install web deployment projects
- add web deployment project to your solution
- setup the solution configuration manager to have a "Deployment" build configuration
- get team city to use this build switch when running the build
- have a beer and wonder in glory at your automagical awesomenesss

Comment: note, this answer no longer relevant for vs2013+ since they removed Web Deployment Projects

Answer (score 10):

Typically what I do is to create a Wix installer.  A Wix project can be build with MsBuild so you should have no problems there.

Also I would recommend looking at the following MsBuild extensions for the automated deployment:

http://www.codeplex.com/MSBuildExtensionPack
http://msbuildtasks.tigris.org/

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 10):

We are using [Octopus Deploy](http://octopusdeploy.com/) to manage our environments on top of Team city.

As a Build Process we have a Octopus Release and Octopus Deploy Creating a Release in Octupus which is then also automatically Deployed;

Since Octopus is managing our Environments it also provided variables which we use extensively and can use the same build to create a new environment all together.

Answer (score 4):

Please also consider a Deployer plugin from one of the TeamCity developers: http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Deployer+plugin

Comment: The Deployer plugins are now integrated into TeamCity 10+