# How to precompile ASP.NET web application from TeamCity?

Tags: asp.net, deployment, continuous-integration, compilation, teamcity

I have a question about precompiling ASP.NET web application projects from TeamCity. This is sort of a follow-up question to the following thread:

[How to deploy after a build with TeamCity?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1987507/how-to-deploy-after-a-build-with-teamcity)

I'm done implementing CI from unit testing to autodeploy using the above thread and now I'd like to complement the process with precompiling the project. The project is rather large and I want to avoid any unnecessary delays in the response time after a new deploy.

So, is there a way to do this from TeamCity? Like calling MSBuild with some specific arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, it can be done with a custom MSBuild script. Here's the one we run to precompile our ASP.NET MVC 3 website (not that it really varies by ASP.NET version).

First it runs the regular build by running MSBuild against the solution file, then runs this custom MSBuild code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">

  <Import Project="$(MSBuildToolsPath)\Microsoft.CSharp.targets" />
  <Import Project="$(MSBuildExtensionsPath)\MSBuildCommunityTasks\MSBuild.Community.Tasks.Targets"/>

  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebProject>Web\ChatPast.Web\ChatPast.Web.csproj</WebProject>
    <WebProjectFolder>Web\ChatPast.Web</WebProjectFolder>
    <WebPublishFolder>ChatPastWebPublish</WebPublishFolder>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <ZipFiles Include="$(teamcity_build_workingDir)\src\ChatPast\$(WebPublishFolder)\**\*.*" />
  </ItemGroup>

  <Target Name="Build">
      <!-- Compilation of all projects -->
      <MSBuild Projects="ChatPast.sln" Properties="Configuration=Release"/>

      <!-- Creating web publish folder. -->
      <RemoveDir Directories="$(WebPublishFolder)"/>
      <MakeDir Directories="$(WebPublishFolder)"/>

      <!-- Running ASP.NET publish -->
      <MSBuild Projects="$(WebProject)"
           Targets="ResolveReferences;_CopyWebApplication"
           Properties="Configuration=Release;WebProjectOutputDir=..\..\$(WebPublishFolder);OutDir=..\..\$(WebPublishFolder)\bin\" />

  </Target>
</Project>
```